# Pyautogui locate on screen doesnt find the object

Tags: python, bots, pyautogui

I'm trying to detect image on screen and thanks to this click on it. I'm doing this with pyautogui.locateteCenterOnScreen. I am watching tutorials and read the documentation. But even with that after rewriting code from documentation and copying the graphics from from the documentation it doesn't found this image. I'm trying to move my mouse over the calculator but it doesn't work like in the documentation. File kalk.png is the file on calculator picture. Even after opening paint with only photos of this calculator pyautogui doesn't find it. I have opencv so the confidence should work. What is the cause of that and how to make it work? I am working on macos. The same code works fine on windows. What is wrong with that code? kalk.png is the picture of calculator from the https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html
On windows my mouse goes to this calculator but on mac I got the error
**cannot unpack nontype object**. It means that program didn't find the image

```
    time.sleep(3)
    x,y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("kalk.png", grayscale=True, confidence=.5)
    pyautogui.moveTo(x,y,1)
    pyautogui.click()
```

Comment: [mre] required. welcome. [tour], [ask] (show your efforts/research) -- vary the confidence?

Comment: I corrected that and to me seems that something is wrong when I run it on macos. But I don't have any idea how to improve that.

Comment: Also add a screenshot of your calculator app.